# Django select from related model

Tags: sql, django, django-models

i have 3 django models:

```
class Property(object):
   name = ...
class Object(object):
    text = ...
    data_related = models.ManyToManyField('Property',related_name='property_related', through="ObjectProperty")

class ObjectProperty(object):
    extra_data = ...
```

i need to select object that has at least 2 properties at the same time.
How can i do it?

For example, Object = [lamp, table, car, pen,...]
Property = [round, red, white, invisible, soft,...]
I want to find white round and soft object.

I d like to do it in in 1 queryset

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this:

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import Count

_objects = Object.objects.filter(
    data_related__name__in=['round', 'soft']).annotate(
    count_objects=Count('id')).filter(count_objects__gt=1)
```

Comment: Your query means that object has soft or white property, but i want it has them both